# How to efficiently load large training data too big for RAM for training in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've got around 10 GB of training data in numpy array format. However, my RAM is not big enough to load the data and the tensorflow 2.0 model at the same time. I've done plenty of research into tf.data, tf.TFRecords and generators, but I'm stuck in the actual implementation of the training loop. I currently have the following standard training loop, when using a loadable subset of the data to test whether everything worked.

The options I considered are:

1) Splitting the 10GB of numpy files into a large number of tf.TFRecords files (shuffled) with each being the size of the BATCH_SIZE and then loading them in every train_step and epoch

2) Splitting the 10GB of numpy files into smaller files of 1-2 GB each (shuffled) and then sequentially training the model by loading the smaller files every epoch sequentially

Is there a best practice for this, or a better option I am not considering? I imagine this should be a trivial problem, but I can't find any good solutions online.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get the original_dataset
    #train_dataset, valid_dataset
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((mtr, labels))
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=mtr.shape[0]).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    valid_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_mtr, val_labels))
    valid_dataset = valid_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    # create model
    model = get_model()

    # define loss and optimizer 
    loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-04, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08,)

    train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
    train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')

    valid_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='valid_loss')
    valid_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='valid_accuracy')

    @tf.function
    def train_step(images, labels):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = model(images, training=True)
            loss = loss_object(y_true=labels, y_pred=predictions)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
        train_loss(loss)
        train_accuracy(labels, predictions)

    @tf.function
    def valid_step(images, labels):
        predictions = model(images, training=False)
        v_loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
        valid_loss(v_loss)
        valid_accuracy(labels, predictions)

    # start training
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        train_loss.reset_states()
        train_accuracy.reset_states()
        valid_loss.reset_states()
        valid_accuracy.reset_states()
        step = 0
        for imgs, lbls in train_dataset:
            step += 1
            train_step(imgs, lbls)
            print("Epoch: {}/{}, step: {}/{}, loss: {:.5f}, accuracy: {:.5f}".format(epoch + 1, EPOCHS, step, math.ceil(mtr.shape[0] / BATCH_SIZE),
                                                                                     train_loss.result(), train_accuracy.result()))
        for valid_images, valid_labels in valid_dataset:
            valid_step(valid_images, valid_labels)

        print("Epoch: {}/{}, train loss: {:.5f}, train accuracy: {:.5f}, "
              "valid loss: {:.5f}, valid accuracy: {:.5f}".format(epoch + 1, EPOCHS, train_loss.result(),
                                                                  train_accuracy.result(), valid_loss.result(), valid_accuracy.result()))

    model.save_weights(filepath=save_model_dir, save_format='tf')
```

**Based on the answer below this seemed to work:**

```
def load_data(filename: tf.Tensor):
     coll = pickle.load(open("./TrainData2016/%s" %(str(filename.numpy().decode('utf-8'))), "rb")) #coll[0] = data, coll[1] = label
     return tf.convert_to_tensor(coll[0],dtype=tf.float32), tf.convert_to_tensor(coll[1],dtype=tf.int32)

filenames = os.listdir("./TrainData2016") # You can just shuffle this array and not use tf.data.Dataset.shuffle()
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(func=load_data, inp=[x], Tout=(tf.float32, tf.int32)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the `map` function from tf.data.Dataset? I mean instead of loading images you can have an array with the filenames only have a look at the example below:

```
def load_img(filename):
   # Read image file
   img = tf.io.read_file(....)
   img = tf.io.decode_png(img) # have a look at tf.io.decode_*

   # Do some normalization or transformations if needed on img 

   # Add label
   label = associated_image_label() # associate the needed lable to your image

   return img, label

filenames = os.listdir("./images_dir") # You can just shuffle this array and not use tf.data.Dataset.shuffle()

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_img)

# Create batches and prefetch
```

This way you will load only the batch of images for your train_step only

Comment: Thanks for the response. So this is in fact the solution to my suggestion 1). 
Is this the best practice and most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: It is similar to what you are suggesting by creating different TFRecords but it does not require you to create TFRecords. I think it is the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

how about using keras with train on batch?

```
Model.train_on_batch(

    x,

    y=None,

    sample_weight=None,

    class_weight=None,

    reset_metrics=True,

    return_dict=False,
)
```

https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/